# How to disable deduction of a template if an array is passed?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a sum function so that numbers and arrays fall into its different specializations.

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,const T*>,T>
 sum(T arg1, T arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

template<typename T, std::size_t L1, std::size_t L2>
void sum(const T(&first)[L1], const T(&second)[L2]) {
    std::cout << "here";

}
```

I wrote two such functions, but for some reason the array still passes into 2 functions.

```
 int mass1[4], mass2[5];
 sum(mass1, mass2);// more than 
 sum("hi", " there");// 1 instance
 std::cout << sum(5, 4);
```

I thought it was possible to compare via decay, but it doesn't work

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,const T*>,T>
```

Then i tried :

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<T>, T>
```

But this also does not disable the transfer of the array.

I realized that I would solve the problem if the parameters would be like links:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,const T*>,T>
 sum(T&& arg1, T&& arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

But I'm interested in solving the problem without using references?

Comment: when you say "without using links" do you mean without references?

Comment: why without references? I mean you are passing the arrays by reference, but you want to non array to pass by value, right?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes, I would like to pass by value

Comment: What is the intended meaning of `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,const T*>`?  There is no type `T` that would _decay_ to `const T*`.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm still learning and maybe this is wrong,but don't arrays decay into ```const T*```?  if we pass it without a reference

Comment: A `T[]` array decays to a `T*`. [std::decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) removes cv-qualification, i.e. everything has both `const` and `volatile` stripped from it.

Comment: @Alpharius you are correct that arrays decay to pointers, but `T` decaying to `const T*` does not communicate that.  If `T` is an array, it would decay to a pointer, but not a pointer to `const T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) to check for and exclude pointer types:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<std::decay_t<T>>, T>
sum(T arg1, T arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KjtCpvihVrAcw1Bl)

---

But note - the type of `arg1 + arg2` can be larger than `T` due to [implicit promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) rules. It's safer to use `auto` return type:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<std::decay_t<T>>, int> = 0>
auto sum(T arg1, T arg2) {
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what ```int> = 0>``` means ?

Comment: The second template argument of `enable_if_t` is a type, which is present if enabled. In the former example, you make use of that type by using it as the return value. But if your return value is going to be `auto` anyway, you need to find somewhere else to make use of the `enable_if_t`. In this case as a non-type template parameter, which if present has no effect on the function but if absent causes an SFINAE non-instantiation of the function. The `=0` provides a default value for the non-type parameter so calling code doesn't have to specify.

Comment: @NathanPierson That is, if the instantiation is correct, then we get int=0 ,which does not affect anything . Don't you have to give it a name?I just don't remember such nameless assignments.

Comment: Just like how in a function definition you don't need to provide a name for a parameter that isn't actually used in the body of the function, you don't need to provide a name for the non-type template parameter because nothing tries to access its value.

Comment: @NathanPierson thank you for your help in the answers here and above :)